# Encountered the error when using HTTP client library in Python

Tags: python-3.x, http.client

I'm using the HTTP client library to send a RESTful GET to a server. This is my code:

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("")
headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG.....JNa0UyT" }
conn.request("GET", "https://xxxx-xxxx.auth0.com/api/v2/jobs/job_xxxxxx", headers=headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

And this is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getResult.py", line 4, in <module>
    conn.request("GET", "https://xxxxxx.auth0.com/api/v2/jobs/job_xxxxxx", headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1252, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 849, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 693, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I don't know why. Could I have a help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPConnection), you should instantiate the connection with the hostname and port, and then perform the GET only with the endpoint string.
You are actually asking the server "" the resource "https://xxxx-xxxx.auth0.com/api/v2/jobs/job_xxxxxx"

[Examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#examples)

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("https://xxxx-xxxx.auth0.com")
headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbG.....JNa0UyT" }
conn.request("GET", "/api/v2/jobs/job_xxxxxx", headers=headers)
```

Anyway, I suggest you to use [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests) for making HTTP calls. It's the de facto library in this context.